# Export konva to image in server side without render

Tags: node.js, express, konvajs

I have a template for image and when user change image inside template, server will automatically render a new image for user. That's all I want to make.

I have a json from template which I created before. And now i want to export it on server side (expressjs, restful api) with Konva init by json.

When I try this code

```
import {Stage} from 'konva/lib/core';
app.get('/', (_req: Request, res: Response, _next: NextFunction) =>
    res.status(200).send({
        message: loadKonvaJson(),
    }),
);


const loadKonvaJson = () => {
    let stage = new Stage({
        container: 'container'
    });

    return stage.toDataURL({pixelRatio: 1});
}
```

I have an error

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.createCanvasElement (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\node_modules\konva\lib\Util.js:355:22)
    at getDevicePixelRatio (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\node_modules\konva\lib\Canvas.js:26:30)
    at SceneCanvas.Canvas (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\node_modules\konva\lib\Canvas.js:46:74)
    at new SceneCanvas (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\node_modules\konva\lib\Canvas.js:112:28)
    at Stage._buildDOM (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\node_modules\konva\lib\Stage.js:717:29)
    at new Stage (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\node_modules\konva\lib\Stage.js:62:15)
    at loadKonvaJson (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\index.ts:20:17)
    at exports.app.get (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\index.ts:17:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\victorlee\Desktop\OmgGame\render-image-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use `container` property when you are trying to use `Konva` from nodejs. Just:

```js
let stage = new Stage({});
```

`Konva` is trying to find the container in the DOM, but there is not DOM in nodejs env.

**Update:** also for the nodejs environment you have to use `konva-node` package:

```js
cont Konva = require('konva-node');

const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I removed `container` but the problem doesn't go away.

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce it without a container. Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: I see. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it by creating stage without container!

Answer (score 1):

konva is a great javascript library this is updated information for export server side

you can install konva and canvas library

```
npm install konva canvas
```

and you can run this code on the server side

```
import Konva from 'konva';

const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
});
```

For more information follow this link https://github.com/konvajs/konva#4-nodejs-env